# Editing .html files using Python?

Tags: python

I want to delete everything from my html file and add `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>`.

Here is my code so far:

```
with open('table.html', 'w'): pass
table_file = open('table.html', 'w')
table_file.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>')
```

After i run my code, `table.html` is now empty. Why?

How can I fix that?

Comment: You are missing the point of the `with` block...

Comment: with open('table.html', 'w'): pass ; deletes everything from my file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're not closing the file and the first line is doing nothing, so you could do 2 things.

Either skip the first line and close the file in the end:

```
table_file = open('table.html', 'w')
table_file.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>')
table_file.close()
```

or if you want to use the `with` statement do it like this:

```
with open('table.html', 'w') as table_file:
  table_file.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>')
  # Write anything else you need here...
```

Comment: You don't need `table_file.close()` with the `with` statement

Comment: Thanks re provato.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('table.html', 'w'): pass 
   table_file = open('table.html', 'w')
   table_file.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>')
```

This would open the file table.html two time's and your not closing your file properly too.

If your using **with** then :

```
with open('table.html', 'w') as table_file: 
   table_file.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>')
```

**with** closes the file automatically after the scope.

Else you have to manually close the file like this:

```
table_file = open('table.html', 'w')
table_file.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>')
table_file.close()
```

and you don't have to use the **with** operator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `with open('table.html', 'w'): pass`. Try the following.

```
with open('table.html', 'w') as table_file:
    table_file.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>')
```

You're currently not closing the file, so the changes aren't being written to disk.

Comment: with open('table.html', 'w'): pass ; deletes everything from my file

Comment: But why? You're doing the same one line after that.